# Plantilla responsive con blade (laravel)

Tags: html, css

tengo un proyecto con laravel 6 y estoy intentando hacer un diseño responsive muy simple para eso tengo este layout con estos archivos.

El layout principal donde cargo las distintas secciones es este

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('includes.user.head')
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row" style="background: #343a40">
        @include('includes.user.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">

        @yield('content')

    </div>

    <div>
        @yield('script')
    </div>

    <footer class="row">
        @include('includes.user.footer')
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Luego tengo los distintos includes como el "include.user.head" donde cargo todas las librerias (jquery , font-awesome, ...)

Y luego tendria una plantilla blade que tiene esta estructura

```html
@extends('layouts.user')

@section('content')



<div id="diet-list">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h1 class="mt-3">Inicio</h1>
    </div>
     
  Página de pruebas
</div>
@endsection
```

Esto me funciona, el diseño se adapta bien a la pantalla del PC pero si lo miro desde mobile no.
Por eso motivo pido ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te hace falta ya no es de laravel sino de frontend, específicamente bootstrap.
Necesitas irle dando a tu plantilla cuantas columnas va a ocupar cada cosa según la resolución de la pantalla (col-lg-2) e ir haciendo los media queries.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la verdad que en temas de frontend voy algo justo, me podrías pasar un enlace de un ejemplo para lo que me comentas? gracias

Comment: Con la documentación de bootstrap vas a comprender lo de las 12 columnas o consigue un curso de bootstrap, yo también para maquetado no soy muy bueno y se lo paso a quien si sabe, la verdad me da flojera el maquetado.